# Extracting syntactic information from tweets using DBSCAN

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I am attempting to use minimum edit distance with DBSCAN to extract high-occurrence syntactic structures of tweets.

I POS tag 10k tweets, then precomputed their min-ed distance and store it in a distance matrix.  I then give the distance matrix to DBSCAN.  No matter how large or small my eps and min_sample size are, I don’t get more than 4 clusters (eps=1, min_sample=13).  With data of this size the syntactic structure should produce more and/or larger clusters.

Here’s my working theory of what’s happening:

- A has an edit-distance of 1 to B
- B has an edit-distance of 1 to C
- C has an edit-distance of 2 to A
- Even though A and C have an edit-distance of 2, they are put in the same cluster given their relationship to B.

Let me know if there is something you believe I am missing or if there is another algorithm that might help me accomplish the same clustering task.

```
db = DBSCAN(eps=3, min_samples=10, metric='precomputed')
db.fit(df)
print (set(db.labels_))
{0, -1}
```

I chose DBSCAN since I do not know the number of clusters that will occur.

Comment: In your example, B needs to have 12 neighbors with edit distance 1, otherwise they all will remain noise. I'm not surprised parameter tuning is hard on this data, because edit distance is very coarse, but you can't fix that.

Comment: If I change the edit distance to any higher number than 1 the set of labels becomes {0, -1},  giving a single large cluster.

Comment: The longest string is 33 POS characters long,  while the shortest is 5, I have tried this with 50k POS tweets and the same issue persists.

Comment: You could try normalized edit distance, but I doubt it will help much. It's the data, not the method, that is too coarse.